# Javascript convention - excessive use of `await`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Нello! I want to know if I'm overusing the `await` keyword.

For a contrived example, let's say we need to get a filepath from some remote url, and then read a file with that filepath:

```
let requestHttpBody = async url => {/* ... returns http response body ... */};
let readFile = async filename => {/* ... returns file contents ... */};

let readFileBasedOnRequest = async () => {
  let filename = await requestHttpBody('www.giveMeFileName.pls');
  return await readFile(filename); // THIS LINE contains the `await` I'm concerned with!
};
```

Per the comment, this is where I'm unsure the `await` keyword ought to be used. The data being returned is already the result of an `async` function (in this case `readFile`) and is already a promise. This code runs the same with or without that `await`.

This code pattern is very common. **Should I use `await`??** Is there any well-accepted convention here? Are there differences depending on whether it's used, maybe subtleties in `nextTick` timing? Or is this totally a matter of preference and not worth fretting about?

Comment: Just use `return readFile(filename)` either way `readFileBasedOnRequest()` is returning a promise that resolves when `readFile()` resolves.

Comment: Subleties in timing, yes. Nothing you should need to worry about though.